# Axiomatizable classes

Tags: model-theory

Are the statements below true or false:

- The class of finite sets is axiomatizable
- The class of infinite sets is axiomatizable
- The class of infinite sets is finitely-axiomatizable
- The class of fields of characteristic 0 is axiomatizable
- The class of fields of characteristic $\neq$ 0 is axiomatizable
- The class of fields of characteristic 0 is finitely-axiomatizable

---

I think I need to use the following criterion:
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a non-trivial ultrafilter on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathcal{K}$ a class of structures of the same (countable) signature. Then $\mathcal{K}$ axiomatizable iff $\mathcal{K}$ closed under elementary equivalence and closed under ultraproducts modulo $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I'd have thought this would be easier using compactness, but I suppose you can use ultraproducts if you want. Anyway: the first step is to notice that some of these are obviously axiomatizable and write down axioms for them.

Answer (score 1):

> The class of finite sets is axiomatizable

False. A non-trivial ultraproduct of a family of finite sets of increasing size is infinite.

> The class of infinite sets is axiomatizable

True. Just write down "there are at least $n$ distinct elements" for all $n$.

> The class of infinite sets is finitely-axiomatizable

False. If it were finitely axiomatizable, its complement would be axiomatizable.

---

Now repeat!

> The class of fields of characteristic $0$ is axiomatizable

True. Just write down "$\underbrace{1+\dots+ 1}_{n\text{ times}}\neq 0$ for all $n$.

> The class of fields of characteristic $\neq 0$ is axiomatizable

False. A non-trivial ultraproduct of a family of fields of increasing characteristic has characteristic $0$.

> The class of fields of characteristic $0$ is finitely-axiomatizable

False. If it were finitely axiomatizable, its complement would be axiomatizable.